# Can I use another database instead of PostgreSQL in CKAN?

Tags: ckan, database

After visiting the official documentation of CKAN, I was unable to find why are we using a PostgreSQL database in CKAN from its inception.

Is there any way to use another database with CKAN?

Comment: Why would you want to? PostgreSQL is one if the best databases in the world and free

Comment: I have many other databases which are free apart from PostgreSQL.. but I wanted to know why was this database only chosen ?

Comment: Developing for multiple databases introduces overheads and restrictions that generally open source projects don’t need. They chose PostgreSQL because it’s free and better than MySQL. Get over it or use something else

Answer (score 5):

No, the only currently supported database backend is PostgreSQL. It was chosen as it is an open source, well supported and widely available solution.
Support for other backends would need to be added to the core library as new feature (CKAN uses SQLAlchemy as ORM, which would help). If someone is up for it they can check the [contributing](https://ckan.org/community/) docs and get in touch with the maintainers.